# Translation Manager throws error when we add a new Project Type in World Server

Tags: translation-manager, worldserver

For one of the Locale when we add new Project Type to Tridion client at WorldServer, the Translation Manager service at Tridion CM throwing us below error:

```
Tridion.TranslationManager.Service RetrieveFromTranslation An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TranslationSystemTargetLanguage..ctor(String id, String friendlyName, IEnumerable`1 availableWorkflows)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerV11.WorldServerV11Configuration.<GetTargetLanguages>b__62_3(<>f__AnonymousType106`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier1)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerV11.WorldServerV11Configuration.GetTargetLanguages()
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TranslationSystemConfiguration.get_TargetLanguages()
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSourceConfiguration..ctor(TcmUri configuredItemUri, XDocument loadFromXml, UserContext userContext)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationConfiguration.LoadFromXml(TcmUri configuredItemId, XDocument xDocument, UserContext userContext)
```

Would anyone suggest to us what would be the cause for this error?